# Como chamar uma função da ASPX page em outro projeto?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Como chamar uma função da ASPX page em outro projeto?

Ao clicar em inserir chamo um projeto para fazer as regras de negocio, em certo momento preciso chamar uma função C# que está na pagina e depois do retorno dessa função continuar na 
fazendo as regras de negocio.

como chamo essa função?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia passar o método a ser chamador para a BLL como um delegate, e então usar o delegate para chamar o método.

Exemplo:

Código da BLL:

```
public void RegraInserir(Action metodo)
{
    metodo(); // chamando o método passado na forma de delegate
}
```

Código da página:

```
public void buttonInserir_Click(EventArgs e)
{
    businessLayer.RegraInserir(this.Metodo);
}

private void Metodo()
{
    // método que será chamado pela BLL
}
```

Comment: A idéia é boa, o problema é que eu aciono minha BLL com formView com Bind() sem passar por eventos da página.

Comment: Sua BLL teria como implementar um evento então? Dessa forma poderia haver um evento chamado BLLQuerArquivo, que seria associado no `Load` da página ou algum outro lugar que julgue mais apropriado.

Answer (score 1):

Ola.

Para que isso possa ocorrer, será preciso referenciar o seu projeto (não solution) na sua BLL.
Porem, caso você já tenha feito a referencia da BLL na sua aplicação, o VS não irá permitir.

Uma solução que utilizo muito é manter o máximo possível dos métodos na BLL, mesmo que sejá algo específico, assim, caso precise utilizar no aspx ou na própria BLL, basta chamar ela normalmente.

Espero ter ajudado!!!

Comment: É uma função que lê um input file do html e faz o upload do arquivo, por isso tem q estar na página. Mas valeu pela ajuda. vou ver como posso fazer aqui.